# schema option _id: false and document must have an _id before saving error happening

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a user document through this way:

```
// create the document ---------------
const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
let userDoc = await Admin.create({ ...req.body, _id: id, by: id })
```

Schema:

```
adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   // some other fields, firstName, lastName ... etc
   by: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
     ref: 'Admin',
     required: [true, "the 'by' field is required"],
     immutable: true,
   }
}, { _id: false })
```

Model:

```
const Admin = mongoose.model('Admin', adminSchema, 'users')
```

- My schema doesn't have an `_id` property.

Now I want to have the `_id` field and the `by` field has the same value, which is a server-side generated id.

Mongoose is throwing this error:

> Error: MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving at
> .../node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:291:18

### update:

I updated my question, I added the schema options, and now I know the reason why this error is happening. it's because of the `_id: false` schema option that I have set. But I need this option because I don't want to see `_id`s in the responses that I send to the clients. is there a workaround? because this option looks like its doing two unrelated things

Comment: I updated my question, I added the schema options, and now I know the reason why this error is happening. it's because of the `_id: false` schema option that I have set. But I need this option because I don't want to see _id in the responses that I send to the clients. is there a workaround? because this option looks like its doing two unrelated things

Answer (score 1):

## Using Mongoose 6.4

I solved this by removing the `_id: false` schema type option.

and to remove the _id from the responses without having to pollute the routes with [_.omit()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit)s or [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)s everywhere, I added the following schema type options to the schema:

```
toObject: {
    virtuals: true,
    transform(doc, ret) { 
        delete ret._id
    },
},
```

Now the real question is, why does simply adding the option `_id: false` results in the Mongoose error when you're generating the id on the server-side without the help of Mongoose?

> Error: MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving at
> .../node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:291:18

I partially answered my own question, but for this one... I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, if you want the response the user receives to not contain the `_id` you can:

- Get the document
- Remove the `_id` property and return this object without the `_id` (Or create a new object to avoid problems).

A brief example could be:

```js
let responseDoc = await Admin.findOne({ _id: id });
delete responseDoc["_id"]
// responseDoc is now ready for use. Note that if I am not mistaken it is still a document.
```

Comment: yes, but imagine doing that all over the routes, it will pollute the space. there must be a way to abstract this logic within the models. and sometimes this issue becomes over complicated if you have for example nested documents and arrays of nested documents. in this case, I will have to remove the _id everywhere.

Comment: I think there is no way to dynamically hide the `_id` with *mongoose*, someone correct me if I am wrong. The best you can do is to create a function where you remove the `_id` and return the object without `_id`, and import this function in each path where you need it.

Comment: I found it. it solved the two problems. see my answer :D